# What are speech bubbles called in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to add speech bubbles to my Kotlin android app. This would help the user when opening the app for the first time. How can I do this? I couldn't find anything "speech bubble" related in the android docs. Are they called something else or am I missing something?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You appear to be showing tooltips, so something like this: https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon

Comment: Perhaps a ViewPager is what you're looking for. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager

Comment: That's called a tool tip .

Comment: I just realized OP asked about the information popping up near the cursor. Those are indeed tooltips, and @dratenik linked a nice library to do that. ViewPager would be helpfull to implement sliding fragments like in a gallery view (similar to those in the pictures)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have been looking at tooltips but it seems like tooltips are only shown when the user hovers over it/holds the button. I would like to have the message popup when the user opens the app for the first time. So I could say: "First click this button to...." then the message closes when clicked and a new message is shown at the next button with "Now press this button". So I could create a small tutorial.  Isn't this something else than tooltips?

Comment: That linked Balloon library doesn't have to be used that way (only with long-presses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the library shared by dratenik.
https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon

Works great!